# Configurar gxmessage-3.4.3: Package 'gobject-2.0', required by 'pango', not found

Tags: configuración, gtk, dependencias, pango

Estoy tratando de configurar *gxmessage-3.4.3*, y le falta `gobject-2.0`.

> configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0) were not met:
> Package 'gobject-2.0', required by 'pango', not found
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
> See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Registro:

```sh
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for dcgettext... yes
checking if msgfmt accepts -c... yes
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.50.0... 0.51.0 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.34.0
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for PACKAGE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0) were not met:

Package 'gobject-2.0', required by 'pango', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS
and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

***./configure:7278***

```sh
if test -n "$PACKAGE_LIBS"; then
    pkg_cv_PACKAGE_LIBS="$PACKAGE_LIBS"
 elif test -n "$PKG_CONFIG"; then
    if test -n "$PKG_CONFIG" && \
    { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors \"gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0\""; } >&5
  ($PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0") 2>&5
  ac_status=$?
  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  test $ac_status = 0; }; then
  pkg_cv_PACKAGE_LIBS=`$PKG_CONFIG --libs "gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0" 2>/dev/null`
              test "x$?" != "x0" && pkg_failed=yes
else
  pkg_failed=yes
fi
 else
    pkg_failed=untried
fi



if test $pkg_failed = yes; then
    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }

if $PKG_CONFIG --atleast-pkgconfig-version 0.20; then
        _pkg_short_errors_supported=yes
else
        _pkg_short_errors_supported=no
fi
        if test $_pkg_short_errors_supported = yes; then
            PACKAGE_PKG_ERRORS=`$PKG_CONFIG --short-errors --print-errors --cflags --libs "gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0" 2>&1`
        else
            PACKAGE_PKG_ERRORS=`$PKG_CONFIG --print-errors --cflags --libs "gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0" 2>&1`
        fi
    # Put the nasty error message in config.log where it belongs
    echo "$PACKAGE_PKG_ERRORS" >&5

    as_fn_error $? "Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0) were not met:

$PACKAGE_PKG_ERRORS

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS
and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details." "$LINENO" 5
elif test $pkg_failed = untried; then
        { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
    { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
as_fn_error $? "The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS
and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

To get pkg-config, see <http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/>.
See \`config.log' for more details" "$LINENO" 5; }
else
    PACKAGE_CFLAGS=$pkg_cv_PACKAGE_CFLAGS
    PACKAGE_LIBS=$pkg_cv_PACKAGE_LIBS
        { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }

fi
```

Muestra en el archivo `configure` que fue generado con *Autoconf 2.69*:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
# Guess values for system-dependent variables and create Makefiles.
# Generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69 for GNU gxmessage 3.4.3.
#
#
# Copyright (C) 1992-1996, 1998-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
#
# This configure script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Comment: La pregunta lógica es ... ¿ Tienes instalado el paquete que te está pidiendo ?

Comment: @Trauma ¿Cómo puedo saber si lo tengo instalado?

Comment: @Trauma Ya respondí la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que hay que hacer es ver la variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
echo PKG_CONFIG_PATH '$PKG_CONFIG_PATH'
```

> /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig

Se puede ver la lista de todas las carpetas... Para entender mejor, las veo separadas en líneas:

```
echo PKG_CONFIG_PATH '$PKG_CONFIG_PATH' | tr ":" "\n"
```

Me encuentro con lo siguiente:

```
/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
/usr/share/pkgconfig
/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig
```

Ahora miro las carpetas una por una para ver qué tiene:

```
ls /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig
```

> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig': No such file or directory

```
ls /usr/local/share/pkgconfig
```

> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/share/pkgconfig': No such file or directory

```
ls /usr/lib64/pkgconfig

Qt.pc            QtXmlPatterns.pc            gstreamer-gl-egl-1.0.pc     libdebuginfod.pc
Qt3Support.pc        dbus-glib-1.pc              gstreamer-gl-prototypes-1.0.pc  libdw.pc
QtCLucene.pc         gail-3.0.pc                 gstreamer-gl-wayland-1.0.pc     libelf.pc
QtCore.pc        gdk-3.0.pc              gstreamer-gl-x11-1.0.pc     libiodbc.pc
QtDBus.pc        gdk-broadway-3.0.pc             gstreamer-net-1.0.pc        libmariadb.pc
QtDeclarative.pc     gdk-wayland-3.0.pc          gstreamer-pbutils-1.0.pc    libnsl.pc
QtDesigner.pc        gdk-x11-3.0.pc              gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0.pc   librtmp.pc
QtDesignerComponents.pc  glib.pc                 gstreamer-riff-1.0.pc       libthai.pc
QtGui.pc         gmodule.pc              gstreamer-rtp-1.0.pc        mariadb.pc
QtHelp.pc        gmp.pc                  gstreamer-rtsp-1.0.pc       pango.pc
QtMimeTypes.pc       gmpxx.pc                gstreamer-sdp-1.0.pc        pangocairo.pc
QtMultimedia.pc      gobject-introspection-1.0.pc        gstreamer-tag-1.0.pc        pangofc.pc
QtNetwork.pc         gobject-introspection-no-export-1.0.pc  gstreamer-video-1.0.pc      pangoft2.pc
QtOpenGL.pc      gstreamer-1.0.pc            gthread.pc          pangoot.pc
QtScript.pc      gstreamer-allocators-1.0.pc         gtk+-3.0.pc             pangoxft.pc
QtScriptTools.pc     gstreamer-app-1.0.pc            gtk+-broadway-3.0.pc        pupvm.pc
QtSql.pc         gstreamer-audio-1.0.pc          gtk+-unix-print-3.0.pc      python-3.9-embed.pc
QtSvg.pc         gstreamer-base-1.0.pc           gtk+-wayland-3.0.pc         python-3.9.pc
QtTest.pc        gstreamer-check-1.0.pc          gtk+-x11-3.0.pc         tcl.pc
QtUiTools.pc         gstreamer-controller-1.0.pc         isl.pc              x11-xcb.pc
QtWebKit.pc      gstreamer-fft-1.0.pc            jemalloc.pc             x11.pc
QtXml.pc         gstreamer-gl-1.0.pc             json-glib-1.0.pc
```

Se puede ver que necesita archivos con extensión `pc`... Además, puede verse que en el nombre del archivo está la versión. Recuerdo el error:

> configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.4.0) were not met:
> Package 'gobject-2.0', required by 'pango', not found

Esto hace suponer que el archivo necesario se llama `gobject-2.0.pc`. Ahora no queda otra alternativa que seguir estos pasos:

1. Buscar el nombre `gobject-2.0.pc` en https://rpmfind.net/

- https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gobject-2.0.pc&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

2. No hubo resultados, mejor buscar `gobject-2.0`

- https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gobject-2.0&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

3. Lo encontró, ahora ver el nombre del paquete, sale `glib2-2.68.2-1.fc35.x86_64.html`, evitando todo lo que viene después del primer guión o signo de resta (`-`) queda `glib2`.

[image: Buscar en rpmfind]

Entonces hay que ir a la página del sistema operativo que está instalado, en mi caso como estoy en *PuppyLinux* tengo *Slackware*.

- http://slackware.uk/slackware/slackware64-current/slackware64/

Buscar el paquete `glib2`:

- http://slackware.uk/search?p=%2Fslackware%2Fslackware64-current%2Fslackware64%2F&q=glib2

Hay tres encontrados:

```
• /slackware/slackware64-current/slackware64/l/glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txt
• /slackware/slackware64-current/slackware64/l/glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz
• /slackware/slackware64-current/slackware64/l/glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz.asc
3 items found.
```

El que hay que elegir es el de extensión `txz`:

- http://slackware.uk/slackware/slackware64-current/slackware64/l/glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz

El gestor de paquetes `ppm` cuando instala `glib2`, no puede instalarlo correctamente, porque descarga un HTML en vez de un `txz`, se movió el enlace y por eso no lo puede descargar, aún así aparece como instalado.

Hay paquetes que incluso pueden instalarse arriba cuando dice que está instalado, y otros que no se pueden instalar cuando no muestra que está instalado.

El *HTML* descargado como `txz` se muestra así:

[image: html descargado como txz]

Por este motivo no hay que usar el gestor de paquetes, o usarlo lo menos posible, hay cosas que se instalan mal y otras que no se descargan.

Como el paquete aparece como instalado, es necesario extraerlo manualmente con *File-Roller* a la carpeta `/`.

Con esto ya el `configure` no debería dar ese error... Si ocurre un error similar, hay que buscar el nuevo archivo faltante en *RPMFind* para saber cómo se llama el paquete necesario.

## Alternativa:

Usar la *API* de https://packages.slackware.com/ y buscar `gobject-2.0`, se pone al final de la *URL*... Hay que tener guardado este enlace largo ya que de manera predeterminada no admite el método *GET*, solo el *POST*.

- https://packages.slackware.com/?release=slackware64-current&mode=content&result=1000&extra=on&pasture=on&patches=on&slackware=on&source=on&testing=on&search=gobject-2.0

  ```
    Nr  Location    Package Content
    1   slackware64/a   aaa_libraries-15.0-x86_64-7.txz usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6800.2
    2   slackware64/d   vala-0.52.4-x86_64-1.txz    usr/share/vala-0.52/vapi/gobject-2.0.vapi
    3   slackware64/d   vala-0.52.4-x86_64-1.txz    usr/share/vala-0.52/vapi/gobject-2.0.deps
    4   slackware64/l   glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz   usr/lib64/pkgconfig/gobject-2.0.pc
    5   slackware64/l   glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz   usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6800.3-gdb.py
    6   slackware64/l   glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz   usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6800.3
    7   slackware64/l   gobject-introspection-1.68.0-x86_64-1.txz   usr/share/gir-1.0/GObject-2.0.gir
    8   slackware64/l   gobject-introspection-1.68.0-x86_64-1.txz   usr/lib64/girepository-1.0/GObject-2.0.typelib
    9   slackware64/l   pygobject-2.28.7-x86_64-8.txz   usr/lib64/pkgconfig/pygobject-2.0.pc

    Finished in 0.96 seconds, Version 1.2, Firefox plugin is here.
  ```

Entonces elegir el que tiene el archivo `gobject-2.0.pc`, es decir, el *4*.

- https://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware64-current&p=glib2-2.68.3-x86_64-1.txz